# java parse date time with milliseconds into date getting parse error

Tags: java, date, parsing

I have a string in which I am finding the datetime with milliseconds as follows:

```
                     Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                    int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Note: zero based!
                    int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                    int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                    int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                    int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
                    int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

                    String monthup = String.valueOf(month);
                    String dayup = String.valueOf(day);
                    String hourup = String.valueOf(hour);
                    String minuteup = String.valueOf(minute);
                    String secondup = String.valueOf(second);
                    String millisup = String.valueOf(millis);

                    if(monthup.length()==1){monthup="0"+monthup;}
                    if(dayup.length()==1){dayup="0"+dayup;}
                    if(hourup.length()==1){hourup="0"+hourup;}
                    if(minuteup.length()==1){minuteup="0"+minuteup;}
                    if(secondup.length()==1){secondup="0"+secondup;}
                    if(millisup.length()==1){millisup="0"+millisup;}
                    if(millisup.length()==2){secondup="00"+millisup;}


                    String timewithmilsec = year+ monthup + dayup+ hourup+ minuteup+ secondup+ millisup;
                    System.out.println(timewithmilsec);
```

I am getting a value: `20151020115216690` which is obviousely correct.

I want to parse it to `java Date format`. 
What I did is as follows:

```
try{
                    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdHHmmssaaa");
                    Date date = formatter.parse(timewithmilsec);
                    System.out.println(date);
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
```

I am getting an error as follows:

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20151020115247995"`

Comment: You only have one `d` and `aaa` isn't doing what you (apparently) think it's doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have only one `d` in your format, but are padding the day to two characters, also, according to the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)...

```
a   Am/pm marker    Text    PM
```

which isn't a millisecond place holder, I think you mean `SSS`

For example...

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = now.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1; // Note: zero based!
int day = now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = now.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int millis = now.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);

String monthup = String.valueOf(month);
String dayup = String.valueOf(day);
String hourup = String.valueOf(hour);
String minuteup = String.valueOf(minute);
String secondup = String.valueOf(second);
String millisup = String.valueOf(millis);

if (monthup.length() == 1) {
    monthup = "0" + monthup;
}
if (dayup.length() == 1) {
    dayup = "0" + dayup;
}
if (hourup.length() == 1) {
    hourup = "0" + hourup;
}
if (minuteup.length() == 1) {
    minuteup = "0" + minuteup;
}
if (secondup.length() == 1) {
    secondup = "0" + secondup;
}
if (millisup.length() == 1) {
    millisup = "0" + millisup;
}
if (millisup.length() == 2) {
    secondup = "00" + millisup;
}

String timewithmilsec = year + monthup + dayup + hourup + minuteup + secondup + millisup;
System.out.println(timewithmilsec);

try {
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
    Date date = formatter.parse(timewithmilsec);
    System.out.println(date);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

Which for me prints

```
20151020173034124
Tue Oct 20 17:30:34 EST 2015
```

And while I'm at it, let me introduce you to `String.format`, which can reduce all you `int` to `String` conversion and padding code down to...

```
String timewithmilsec = String.format("%04d%02d%02d%02d%02d%02d%03d", year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millis);
```

> I  am getting Tue Oct 20 12:04:08 IST 2015 but interestingly I did not see any millisecond here

`Date#toString` won't include the milliseconds by default, you will need to supply a `DateFormat` which can.

If I replace the last `System.out.println` with `System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS").format(date));` it prints something like

```
20 Oct 2015 17:37:14.856
```

(for the value `20151020173714856`)

Comment: I am getting `Tue Oct 20 12:04:08 IST 2015` but interestingly I did not see any millisecond here

Comment: @Santhucool `Date#toString` won't normally print the `milliseconds`, you need to supply a format which does

Comment: ok buddy if you can help me to get 'Tue Oct 20 12:04:08 IST 2015' to 'Tue Oct 20 12:04:08 IST 2015' then my problem solved!! I mean the other way after conversion!!

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation letter `S` responds to milliseconds so your format should look like this `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");` (you have one `d` in your format).

Comment: I am getting `Tue Oct 20 12:04:08 IST 2015` but interestingly I did not see any millisecond here

Comment: If you would like to print date with milliseconds you should create another instance of `SimpleDateFormat` with format of your desired output and then print it like `System.out.println(sdf.format(date));` where `sdf` is new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` and `date` is date from your code.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the missing "d" in the date format, where [@MadProgrammer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992484/madprogrammer) depicts.

In addition, the generation of the string representation of the date should be reconsidered. You should use `SimpleDateFormat.format()` to generate date string as in the sample code below:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmssSSS");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(now.getTime());
System.out.println("Formatted date: " + formattedDate);
```

And the output will be in a format that you requested.

```
Formatted date: 20151020094934279
```